# Rails how to create live video streaming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, live

Is there a gem or a technology that can make live video streaming via webcam with rails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RoR (or anything similar really) isn't relevant here.  Fire up Flash Media Server or Red5 and utilize a Flash player.

First you need to encode the video with something. [Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) will do the trick.  This will take audio/video inputs and compress it down, usually to H.264 or VP6.  It then sends the stream data to your server.

Your server (such as [Red5](http://www.red5.org/)) takes this data and distributes it to clients.

On the client side, you need something to play this video.  Flash is still the most compatible (currently anyway... HTML5 will change that).  A common Flash video player is [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/), but you have other choices as well.

Comment: @tzown there's no way you could have possibly done any research into what this answer proposed in those two minutes. Google is your friend.

Comment: @tzown, see my clarification.

Comment: Is it possible to record the live streaming video automatic?

Comment: How is that done with Javascript or with the Flash media server?

Comment: @tzown, at this point, I have no idea what you are asking.  Post a separate question for specifically what you want.

Comment: @Brad: As vague and not useful as this question was, your answer helped me quite a bit, so thank you for answering.

Comment: Hi @Brad For someone arriving here in 2022, would the answer still be the same?